# How do I get the profile pic from the facebook registration plug in?

Tags: plugins, facebook-javascript-sdk, registration, profile, image

Below is the plug in code I got from the fb documentation. If I want to store a users profile pic to my database along with other registration info, what do I do?

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration?
             client_id=113869198637480&
             redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Ftools%2Fecho%2F&
             fields=name,birthday,gender,location,email"
        scrolling="auto"
        frameborder="no"
        style="border:none"
        allowTransparency="true"
        width="100%"
        height="330">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook passes you a `user_id` parameter with the user's Facebook user ID.

Their picture is at `https://graph.facebook.com/<user id>/picture`.

Example: https://graph.facebook.com/70601113/picture for me.

See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/